# How to access a structure variable from within the same structure?

Tags: go, structure

I have this structure:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type X struct {
        x int
    }
    test := []struct {
        a int
        b int
        x X
    }{
        {
            a: 10,
            x: X{
                x: 10,
            },
            b: 5 + x.x,
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(test[0].b)
}
```

I tried multiple ways such as `b:test[0].x.x+5` etc. but it doesn't work. Is there some way to achieve this?

Faced it while using testify library.

Comment: You cannot do this. No matter how hard you try.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Golang, what you want to is to create the instance of struct type `X` outside the struct you want to reference it from:

```
type X struct {
    x int
}
var x = X{x:10}
test := []struct {
    a int
    b int
    x X
}{
    {
        a: 10,
        x: x,
        b: 5 + x.x,
    },
}
```

Self-referencing, circular-referencing are illegal;